# Android Sound Verification

Tags: android

I would like to create an application, which will response on "Clap" sound.

Means, if I have kept my mobile somewhere in my room, and if a clap it will start ringing.

I would like to know how can I compare two sound [incoming sound of clap] and already stored clap sound?

I think I need to create a service which will keep on listening through mobile Microphone, and check for incoming sound.

[If you think any other approach for this application is good/better then please suggest that also.]
Please guys any pointer or any help will be very much appreciated.

---

Thanks for your quick response.

As i have create a service which will continuously record sound from Mic, which class should i use to record the sound MediaRecorder / AudioRecord .

Other requirement is like user can record their own custom music also, to find their phone.
So for eg: if user records some random sound, which will be stored in application.

Now once again user plays the same sound, to find their phone, then how will i compare currently played sound with previously stored sound ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to look into something like Fourier Transform on the inputs. If you're trying to differentiate one sound from another, than you really need to analyze the frequency content of the sound, and not its amplitude. Then you can do some kind of matching by identifying the amplitude of the different frequency peaks, to try to differentiate one sound from another.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your help, i would like to know as i am creating a service which will continuously recording sound from Mic, what should i use to record sound MediaRecorder or AudioRecorder, which onw is good ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience with android sound libraries.

Comment: I would recommend you to use `AudioRecorder` as the raw output data is easy to get. This paper gives you some hints and links how to do so: http://netscale.cse.nd.edu/twiki/pub/Main/Projects/Analyze_the_frequency_and_strength_of_sound_in_Android.pdf

Comment: Hi
I am looking for the same
Did u get any solution for that 
How to implement such code 
If u have solution please share it
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Dipali, I am still looking for solution, if you have found any workaround .. plz share with me as i am stuck at this point..Thanks ..

Comment: @Dipali , were you able to find solution to this problem. I need to implement same kind of functionality in an app, if you were able to find solution please share and help.