# Recording audio from ear speaker in android

Tags: android

I want to know how to record audio from ear speaker (the speaker from which we hear audio of another person while calling).
Thanks

Comment: You can only record through the microphone. Android provides no direct access to the system audio to non-system apps.

Comment: Ya, I agree with you, but how a call recorder app available in playstore record earpiece audio during calling?

Comment: hi :), this looks related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025824/how-to-record-audio-voice-in-background-continuously-in-android

Comment: @TanmayJain does it use root?

Comment: no,it doesnt't require root @TheWanderer

Comment: Thanks a lot,but it's not what am looking for.Like call recorder applications record both voice from earpiece speaker & mic, what I want is to to record only voice from earpiece speaker & not from mic.